# Dplyr mutate : making the difference between vector to be taken element wise and vectors to be taken as vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using dplyr to manipulate data. i have two columns : x and y. In a third column (say z), I'd like to have the first index of y in all the x column.

For instance:

[image]

For the first row I get 4 because 7 is in 4th position in x.

So I have tried

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(z = which (x==y)[1])
```

But the comparison is made elementwise (i.e. I get only fives in z). Hence my question : how to make the difference between vector to be taken element wise and vectors to be taken as vector in dplyr mutate ?

Comment: Probably `mutate(z = match(y, x))`. As long as all the y's are definitely in x.

Comment: Thanks ! That works indeed for this specific case ! (also made me realise that the 2nd value of z should be 3, not 2!). But what about the more general question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr` does not decide whether or not the function is applied element-wise. `mutate` only provides a syntax that lets you use other functions more concisely by recognising that if you refer to `x` inside `mutate`, you probably mean the column `df$x` in `df`. It also does one simple broadcasting step, where if you supply it a function that returns only a single value it will copy it to the whole output.

We can show the same behaviour with `which` and `match` outside of dplyr below. Because `==` does an element-wise comparison your first method returns all `5`. `match` on the other hand, "returns a vector of the positions of (first) matches of its first argument in its second" (from the documentation) which is what you want. I compare the two syntaxes at the bottom to show that the key is the function you supply that determines how inputs are read, not `mutate`.

```r
x = c(1,2,3,7,9)
y = c(7,3,9,1,9)

x == y
#> [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
which(x == y)
#> [1] 5

match(y, x)
#> [1] 4 3 5 1 5

library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x, y)
df$z1 = match(df$y, df$x) # a base R syntax that forces you to specify the data frame name
df <- df %>% mutate(z2 = match(y, x)) # dplyr syntax that is more concise
df # they produce the same result
#>   x y z1 z2
#> 1 1 7  4  4
#> 2 2 3  3  3
#> 3 3 9  5  5
#> 4 7 1  1  1
#> 5 9 9  5  5
```

Created on 2018-06-29 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).